# iOS8: How to modify UITextView dimensions?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, ios8

Here are my attempts, cell is an instance of my prototype cell custom class derived from UITableViewCell. commentLabel is my IBOutlet to a UITextView, inside of the custom class. Scrolling in the UITextView is disabled.

Attempt 1:

```
cell.commentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.commentLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.commentLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.commentLabel.frame.width, 500)
```

Attempt 2:

```
cell.commentLabel.frame.size.height = 500
```

Additional info (maybe unnecessary and irrelevant):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?  If so, adjusting the .frame property will do nothing, you need to update constraint constant instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm using AutoLayout to pin 3 of the sides of the UITextView. I didn't set the bottom constraint, because that's what I want to set manually. So where do I go from here? How do I access the constraints via code?

Comment: I've checked `cell.commentLabel.constraints()` and its contents are empty.

Comment: I posted an answer for you that I hope helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: I've read that many times, but thats about TableView, not TextView. Thanks for trying to interrupt my question though.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons I also used some of that code from that link in the question, incase you skipped over that...

Answer (score -1):

First, create an IBOutlet reference to your height constraint so that you can reference it from code.  I've called mine 'heightConstraint'.

Then:

`heightConstraint.constant = 500;
[cell layoutIfNeeded]; //you many or may not need this li`

Comment: Error: `"heightConstraint" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.`

Comment: Why don't you add more information to your post about your auto layout constraints instead of downvoting and being sarcastic to people trying to help you.

Comment: That wasn't me that downvoted and I can prove that by downvoting again if you'd like me to...? Could it be possible someone else must think your answer is bad?